# How to remove clasterized placemarks in YandexMapKit?

Tags: ios, swift, yandex-maps, yandex-mapkit

I have to show clasterized placemarks in my app. When I add placemarks via `ddPlacemarkWithPoint:` it works. But when I need to remove some of them I get a problem. `YMKClusterizedPlacemarkCollection` has only `clean` method which removes all marks. If I remove all marks and then add a part of them back I see the blinking pins on my map. Then I try to remove mark from `mapView.map.mapObjects` via `removeWithMapObject:`. And this fires an exception and a crash.
`*** Assertion failure in -[YMKMapObjectCollection removeWithMapObject:], ../../../../../../../../idl/ios/impl/YandexMapKit/YMKMapObjectCollection_Binding.mm:398`

Here's my "empty" app that reproduces the issue:

```
    @IBOutlet var mapView: YMKMapView!

    var mapWindow: YMKMapWindow! {
        return mapView.mapWindow
    }
    var map: YMKMap! {
        return mapWindow.map
    }
    var placemarks = [YMKPlacemarkMapObject]()

    var placemarksCollection: YMKClusterizedPlacemarkCollection!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupMap()
        addClusters()
//        addPointsOnMap()
        addPointsToCollection()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.5) {
            self.removePoints()
        }
    }

    func setupMap() {
        let cameraPosition = YMKCameraPosition(target: YMKPoint.moscow,
                                               zoom: 13,
                                               azimuth: 0,
                                               tilt: 0)
        map.isDebugInfoEnabled = true
        map.move(
            with: cameraPosition,
            animationType: YMKAnimation(type: .smooth, duration: 0.3),
            cameraCallback: nil)
    }

    func addClusters() {
        placemarksCollection = map.mapObjects.addClusterizedPlacemarkCollection(with: self)
    }

    func addPointsOnMap() {
        for _ in 0..<5 {
            let placemark = map.mapObjects.addPlacemark(with: YMKPoint(latitude: YMKPoint.moscow.latitude + Double(arc4random() % 10)/1000, longitude: YMKPoint.moscow.longitude + Double(arc4random() % 10)/1000))
            placemarks.append(placemark)
        }
    }

    func addPointsToCollection() {
        for _ in 0..<5 {
            let placemark = placemarksCollection.addPlacemark(with: YMKPoint(latitude: YMKPoint.moscow.latitude + Double(arc4random() % 10)/1000, longitude: YMKPoint.moscow.longitude + Double(arc4random() % 10)/1000))
            placemarks.append(placemark)
        }
        placemarksCollection.clusterPlacemarks(withClusterRadius: 60, minZoom: 10)
    }

    func removePoints() {
        if let placemark = placemarks.last {
            map.mapObjects.remove(with: placemark)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you solve the issue?

Comment: @SergeyDi, I have communicated with yandex developer, and they didn't have any solution for my case ‍♂️, so my team have decided not to clasterize pins. We could use our backend to get clasterized pins, but we didn't

Answer (score 0):

The possibility of removing markers from clusters has been added since version 4.0.0. 
Also, the Yandex team changed the package name from `com.yandex.android:mapkit` to `com.yandex.android:maps.mobile`.

Comment: The question was about iOS